# How do you retrieve the font size of the text editor in a VS extension?

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

You can find the font size by going to:

Tools>Options>Environment>Fonts and Colors>Text Editor>Plain Text

However, if you would like to do this in an VS extension (vsix), you would do something such as the following:

```cs
DTE vsEnvironment = (DTE)GetService(typeof(SDTE));
EnvDTE.Properties propertiesList = vsEnvironment.get_Properties("Environment", "FontsAndColors");
Property prop = propertiesList.Item("TextEditor");
short size = (short)prop.Value;
```

Sadly, I can’t seem to find the magic and secret word to retrieve the needed propertyList.  “FontsAndColors”  and all sensible permutations fail.

**Question**: is there a method to retrieve the existing keys. Or even better, how do you retrieve the font size of the text editor in a VS extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the font size of the text editor:

```cs
    EnvDTE.Properties propertiesList = vsEnvironment.get_Properties("FontsAndColors", "TextEditor");
    Property prop = propertiesList.Item("FontSize");
    int fontSize = (System.Int16)prop.Value;
```

Comment: Do you know where this info can be found on MSDN?

Comment: @HJLebbink See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165642.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awdwz11a.aspx